# System Error 183 from print call (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)

Tags: c++, windows, printing, system-error

I am trying to get a test page printed from the [Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8.1 Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-8-Driver-Samples-5e1aa62e) (the bitmap sample). Since I did not get any print output, I placed a "GetLastError" call after each call to 'DrvWriteSpoolBuf":

```
dwWritten = pDevObj->pDrvProcs->DrvWriteSpoolBuf(pDevObj, (void*)&(pOemPDEV->bmFileHeader), sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));

DWORD pdwReturn = GetLastError();
if (pdwReturn != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    ERR("OEMEndDoc: Error printing=%ld\n", pdwReturn);
```

I received Error 183 !!! From [System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS
183 (0xB7)
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

Alternate version of call above

```
DWORD res = pOemPDEV->pOEMHelp->DrvWriteSpoolBuf(pDevObj, &(pOemPDEV->bmFileHeader), sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwWritten);
```

**I get res=E_FAIL**

(apology for using bold - comments seem to overlook this result though)

How can I get such an error from printing ? (either to LPT1 or FILE: port)

I have tested the code by saving to a bitmap the exact contents I am trying to send to he spooler, the bitmap was created correctly.

...I apologize for not including more code, it is available at the link I posted above... [Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8.1 Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-8-Driver-Samples-5e1aa62e)

Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8.1 Samples\OEM Printer Customization Plug-in Samples\C++\bitmap

Comment: You should only call `GetLastError` if a function actually fails, and is documented as setting the last error code on failure.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out this for a long time, and saw examples on web calling GetLastError... The command does fail since I tried with a version that returns S_OK or S_FAIL... it returned E_FAIL... I was not aware that a specific command has to return the error, I thought the process did ?

Comment: `GetLastError` does exactly what is says, it gets the last error.  If the function you called didn't fail then you're looking at an error that happened somewhere else, probably from a function you didn't call directly and that was likely handled since your function didn't fail.

Comment: My function did fail though. As I explained... when I found a version of it hat returned a fail code...  It is ok, though, please see my answer, I found the cause

Comment: @JonathanPotter - just curious - I have never seen c/c++ functions "documented as setting the last error code on failure" - where would I see that ?

Comment: `GetLastError` is specific to the Windows API, not a c/c++ language feature.  If a function sets the last error on failure it is listed in the documentation generally under Return Values.  Something like `If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.`

Comment: @Thalia how did you build the customization sample on github? I asked this on [community.osr.com](https://community.osr.com/discussion/293569/building-oem-printer-customization-plug-in-samples/p1?new=1) . Could you reply at there if you know the answer?

Comment: @BarisLaPaz I did not create a package.  I called msbuild, then inf2cat in a build script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, because of a function that was implemented and not disabled, there were two different methods to process image data... I was not aware that each sent their output to the spooler (generating the `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`... is my guess)

(more precisely, while I did not implement `FilterGraphics`, but only `ImageProcessing`, I also should have returned `S_FALSE` for `FilterGraphics` in the `GetImplementedMethod`)